# В Android Studio постоянно проваливаюсь в декомпилированный класс

Tags: android-studio, декомпиляция

В Android Studio, если нажать на класс с зажатой клавишей Ctrl, то провалишься в исходный код этого класса, не помню что точно я сделал, но теперь, при нажатии Ctrl на определенный класс, он постоянно проваливается в декомпилированный класс, как вернуть все обратно, чтобы переходить в обычный исходный код?

Например, показывает вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда должно быть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ребята из Гугла когда-то это поломали (помню что работало раньше), наверное руки не доходят пофиксить.

Comment: Дело в том, что отсутствуют сурс файлы для api 26 до сих пор

Comment: @timuruktus, Точно, я понял, спасибо!!!

Comment: Просто в gradle стояла версия 26, я поменял ее на 25 и начал нормально открывать

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, вы открываете файлы классов в левом навигационном окне. Вместо этого найдите исходный код (.`java` файлы) и откройте их - тогда все должно быть нормальным.

(Посмотрите, `homes\Class.java` например, вместо `homes\Class.class...`)

затем для апи 26 сделайте это ,должно помочь

```
cd SDK/sources
cp -R android-25 android-26
cd android-26
vi/emacs/nano package.xml
# Find/replace 25 with 26
vi/emacs/nano source.properties
# Find/replace 25 with 26
```

Затем перезагрузите Android Studio